# disable and then re-enable display on Mac

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, external-display

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to programmatically turn off an external display on a mac through Obj-C. Then, re-enable the display.

Does anyone know how to disable displays and then re-enable them in obj-c?

Thanks.

Comment: The possible dup shows how to sleep the display, but not how to re-enable it...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have seen the code, and was wondering if there was a way just to disable it only on the secondary monitors.